# How to select only .json file using python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, file, tkinter

I am trying to select only .json file. I'm able to select the .json file, but failing to validate the file.

I'm using python 3.7.3 with tkinter. So far I have achieved the following

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import os
import json
import csv
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

def JsonFormat():
    name = askopenfilename(initialdir="../Path/For/JSON_file",
                           filetypes=(("Json File", "*.json"), ("All Files", "*.*")),
                           title="Choose a file."
                           )
    json_string = None
    try:
        with open(name, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
            json_string = f.read()
            parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)
            formatted_json = json.dumps(parsed_json, indent = 4,sort_keys=True)
            with open(name, 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
                f.write(formatted_json)
            messagebox.showinfo("Information","JSON file formatted")
    except Exception:
        messagebox.showerror("Error Message", 'File not selected')
```

All I want to know is how am I suppose to validate that the file I'm reading is in .json format and not in any other format. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does _"failing to validate the file."_ mean? How is it failing? Are you getting errors? Does it think non-json files are json? Does it think json files aren't json?

Answer (score 0):

Why to add All types when needed only json

```
name = askopenfilename(initialdir="../Path/For/JSON_file",
                           filetypes=(("Json File", "*.json"),),
                           title="Choose a file."
                           )
```

using list:

```
name = askopenfilename(initialdir="../Path/For/JSON_file",
                           filetypes=[("Json File", "*.json")],
                           title="Choose a file."
                           )
```

**but failing to validate the file**: where you are failing...please share error

i am sorry if i didn't get you...n less repo so can't comment :(